# asp.net query string databind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a page that loads data from a query string. And creates a link to another page with URL as follows.

```
http://localhost:61279/clubpage.aspx?CategoryID=1
```

When I click on category 1 how do i pull data just relating to that query string.

Some of the code that i have but it is not working.

```
   </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>
        Youth clubs</h2>
    <p>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        EnableViewState="False">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <ul>
            </HeaderTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
               <%-- <%--<%-- You can use an anchor element... --%>
            <%--    <li><a href='youthclubpage.aspx?CategoryID=<%# Eval("YouthClubID") %>'><%# Eval("youthclubname") %></a> - <%# Eval("description") %></li> --%>                

                 <%-- Or a HyperLink Web control...---%>
                <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("youthclubname") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "youthclubpage.aspx?CategoryID=" + Eval("YouthClubID") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                  - <%# Eval("Description") %></li>

            </ItemTemplate>

            <FooterTemplate>
                </ul>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:joanton7865org7272_youthpodcastConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT [youthclubname], [description], [YouthClubID] FROM [youthclublist]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </p>

    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: How are you binding the data? Through code behind? Using a Data Source control?

Comment: This question is too wide. Basically you're requesting us to do everything for you. You should try to tell us what you're having problems with specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the query string via

```
int categoryId = 0;

if(int.TryParse(Request.Params["CategoryID"]), out categoryId))
{
  // query data with categoryID
}
else
{
  // no category id
  Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

Further MSDN info on [Request Params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this, and make sure you use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection 
[SqlCommand Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx)

```
int categoryId = 0;

if(Request["CategoryID"]!=null)
{
categoryID=Convert.ToInt32(Request["CategoryID"]);
SqlConnection ConnObject = new SqlConnection("ConnString of your SQL Provider"); 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select some thing from your table where category_ID=@catID",ConnObject); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catID", categoryId); 
SqlDatareadr dr= cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(dr.read())
{
// use the returned values from DB 
}
}
else
{

//category not exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int CatagoryID = Request["CatagoryID"];

string myQuery = "Select Fields from table where [Filtered column] = " + CatagoryID;
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: SQL Commands shouldn't be built like this. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: it will lead to "SQL injections ", so better ti use parameterized query

Comment: I normally use stored proc's over in - line sql was trying to understand the question better your example is more concise :).